# How to get the complete value of an option tag?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code using php

```
<select id="sem" name="y[]">
    <option>Year</option>
    <?php
        $petsa = new DateTime();
        $yr=$petsa->format('Y');
        $a=$yr+1;//2015
        $b=$yr-1;//2013
        for($y=$b;$y<=$a;$y++)
        {
            $bb = $y+1;
            echo '<option value="'.$y.'"'.'-'.$bb;
                if(isset($_POST['y'])){
                    if (in_array($y."-".$bb,$_POST['y'])){
                        echo 'selected="selected"';
                    }
                echo '/>'.$y."-".$bb;
                }else 
                   echo "<option value ='$y'"."-"."$bb".">".$y."-".$bb;
                   echo "</option>";
                }
      ?>
  </select>

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sem= $_POST['sem'];//this is from other field
    foreach ($_POST['y'] as $yer);


    $osql2 = "INSERT INTO sy VALUES('$sem','$ss')";
    if (mysql_query($osql2)){
        echo "Successfully Added!";
    }
```

This code work well almost but the problem is when i call the value of the option tag it just give me this value `$ss=2014` and it should be like this `$ss=2014-2015`

what is wrong with my code? that code generate SY from 2013-2014 to 2015-2016
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the generated HTML. Look at where the quotes around the attribute value are. They are currently very wrong.

Stop trying to generate HTML by mashing together lots of different strings. It becomes very hard to see what is going on.

```
$value = $y . "-" . $bb;
?>
<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?>">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?>
</option>
<?php
```

Comment: @JakirOnglah Agreed, it is often more useful to concatenate prior to actually using the string

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's your use of quotes here:

```
echo "<option value ='$y'"."-"."$bb".">".$y."-".$bb;
```

I would change it to this:

```
echo "<option value ='$y"."-"."$bb"."'>".$y."-".$bb;
```

I have moved the second `'` to just before the `>` of the opening `option` tag.

The single quote `'` was for the option tag, and the double quote `"` was for the PHP string, you were simply cutting the `value` for `option` short

Comment: ow, is that it? ill try